# C# service to call a form's method (Not UI)

Tags: c#

I have written a c# service to reset my windows XP password. As of now i learned few things about windows service. The main thing is windows service is incompatible with UI. I know that using service cant use form UI([Here is the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159076/windows-services-with-windows-forms-in-the-same-process)). So, by using my service code At least the hard coded password should work. Here i have given the form code. I just want to call the `ResetAdminPass("DillGates");` function in service.

```
    ResetAdminPass("DillGates");//By calling this method works fine in windows form.


    private static void ResetAdminPass(string NewPass)
    {
        //Create New Process
        Process QProc = new Process();

        // Do Something To hide Command(cmd) Window
        QProc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        QProc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

        // Call Net.exe
        QProc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\\windows\\SYSTEM32";
        QProc.StartInfo.FileName = "net.exe";
        QProc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        QProc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        QProc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        QProc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        QProc.StartInfo.Arguments = @" user 5mine " + NewPass;
        QProc.Start();

        // MyProc.WaitForExit();
        QProc.Close();
    }
```

Please do favor for me, with solution/suggestion for my service code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What isn't working?  What indication do you have that there's a problem?

Comment: Your question is very unclear.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Sorry for the unclear explanation. Right now i written a C# service. Using that service i need to reset my windows password. The thing is i can't reset by service(but by windows form it works). I have created a new form within the service project also wring the ResetAdminPass() method. Now, i want to reset by calling the method. Also tried some other code to reset but those are helpless. This is the problem i am facing. Please help me?

Comment: What doesn't work? Does it crash? Is there an exception? What?

Comment: No. its was not working. but at the end i got the simple answer. Here is the code need to be included in service.
Form1 formDig1 = new Form1();
formDig1.Show();